# Facebook Login Problem

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, authentication

I am using codeigniter on my site and I use facebook login to login but I have a problem.
->getUser does not return any data when I try my normal codeigniter project. But, in the new folder which is not related my project I try to login from example.php which comes from facebook sdk it works well.

I have checked everything (autoloads, config, etc.)
I think my problem is about sessions.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Problem has not been solved. Need Help Please...

Comment: Try adding more detail about the problem to your question. Example code, application setup, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you use the new version of [PHP SDK for the Facebook API](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk). I had the same problem with version 3.0.1, that is why I use the previews version 2.1.2 which works just fine.

Unfortunately I don't have time to play with the new version (3.0.1) but there is a very simple example with version 2.1.2:

Config

```
/* application/config/autoload.php */
$autoload['libraries'] = array('template', 'session', 'facebook');
```

Library

```
/* application/libraries/Facebook.php */
require_once("Facebook/2.1.2/facebook.php");
class CI_Facebook extends Facebook {}
```

Template

```
/* application/views/template.php */
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'cookie' => true
));

$session = $facebook->getSession();

$me = null;
// Session based API call.
if ($session) {
  try {
    $uid = $facebook->getUser();
    $me = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
  }
}

// login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($me) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}
?>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId   : '<?php echo $facebook->getAppId(); ?>',
      session : <?php echo json_encode($session); ?>, 
      cookie  : true,
      xfbml   : true
    });

    // whenever the user logs in, we refresh the page
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function() {
      window.location.reload();
    });
  };

  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
  </script>
```